# Which kernel parameters should be adjusted to fix RX overruns?

Tags: networking, centos6, ifconfig

I have a Centos 6 server that handles a lot of traffic. I see RX overruns increasing all the time:

```
RX packets:11191345002 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:35592596 frame:0
TX packets:15262461573 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
RX bytes:1871320014951 (1.7 TiB)  TX bytes:12673638434114 (11.5 TiB)
```

According to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-iface.ifconfig.html

> Receiver overruns usually occur when packets come in faster than the kernel can service the last interrupt.

Which kernel parameters should be adjusted to fix this issue?

Comment: More detail. What is your application doing?

Comment: It's a SMTP server that handles traffic for thousands of customers. Load is usually low ( below 2 ) as the server has a lot of RAM ( 256GB ) and fast SSDs in RAID 6. Our only issue is related to network since during peak times some connections are dropped and the overruns increase when the issue is happening.

Comment: Have you made *any* `/etc/sysctl.conf` modifications?

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using an appropriate `tuned-adm` profile for your I/O configuration. For this setup, it sounds like `yum install tuned-utils` and `tuned-adm profile enterprise storage` would be helpful.

On the kernel side, you can set send/receive buffers:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
```

I'd try those first...

If you still see issues, you can check the NIC ring buffer with `ethtool -g`

```
Ring parameters for eth0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:     4096
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:     256
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     256
```

So you could modify the rx from 256 to 1024 with `ethtool -G eth0 rx 1024`.