# Compare two Linux servers for network configurations

Tags: linux, linux-networking, rhel6

Some guys did initial setup of servers and they moved on now we see lot of network issues on new servers

I want to find a way to compare servers ( New vs old ) to check any specific tuning which was done at network level

OS : RHEL 6.3

Comment: What types of issues are you seeing on the new servers?

Comment: we see packets loss, connection drops and performance issues, its hard to digest server config can cause these issues but i want to look at all possible options

Comment: What type of server hardware is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect all you need to do is compare the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` and `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

There's a chance other steps have been taken for tuning; for instance, the Red hat `tuned-adm` profiles... But I think this requires better troubleshooting steps.

If you're having an issue with NIC buffers, you can also look at the [`ethtool` ring buffer settings](https://serverfault.com/a/707639/13325) on each server.

Comment: Glad to help. What parameter was it?

Comment: After debugging, found out these settings wont help to resolve existing issue but were missing on new batch of servers so its good catch, looks like 2 nic on these servers are connected to different subnets causing chaos Thanks again for pointers